# laravel web app: post requests on production are not stable

Tags: jquery, laravel, google-app-engine, session, post

I'm working on a web application based on laravel framework. In development environment all the routes are working fine. But, after deploying the app into app engine, all of the post requests on production environment are not stable, meaning that it's usually displaying: "The page has expired due to inactivity. 
Please refresh and try again." with status code "419". 
sometimes when I refresh the page couple of times, the app manages to get me to the request view.
I should point out that I included `{{ csrf_field() }}` on every form on the app, also added

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
 });
```

for the requests triggered by JQuery.
Am I missing something here? I'm out of ideas.
please feel free to ask for additional information.

Comment: Meaning of 419: 419 Authentication Timeout denotes that previously valid authentication has expired. It is used as an alternative to 401 Unauthorized in order to differentiate from otherwise authenticated clients being denied access to specific server resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCloud doesn't allow Laravel to edit files, it works on your local setup because there's no specific permission, but GCloud doesn't let Laravel edit the session files.

This means that your session isn't saved anywhere, and it expires before you can even use it.

You should refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session and edit the storage of your session to use something else (like a cookie, or a database).

Comment: sounds very relevant, I will try it out and update you with the outcome.

Comment: Eventually I used Redis, and it's working as a charm. Thanks a lot you saved my day

Comment: Can you please help me to solve the issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69387589/419-page-expired-laravel-page-in-iframe