# 419 page expired laravel page in iframe

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am opening a page developed using `Laravel-7` inside an iframe in an angular project. The page is displaying the records. But while creating or updating a record the page throws 419 error.

I have update the 'same_site' => 'none' and it didn't help.

Both projects are deployed in GCP

I have attached my session.php file .

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
| list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
| must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
|
| Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
|
*/

'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false), 

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Same-Site Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
| take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
| will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
|
| Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
|
*/

'same_site' => 'none',

];
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you verified that your browser/an extension isn't simply blocking 3rd-party cookies to begin with maybe?

Comment: After allowing the cookies also it didn't work .

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I think this is impossible. Save me please

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can play with the `config/session.php` `same_site` value.

```
'same_site' => 'lax'
```

to

```
'same_site' => 'none',
```

add in your .env file

```
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
```

Comment: for localhost  don't use `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true`

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach would be exclude the URIs that are causing the CSRF problem:

```
// FILE: App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken

// The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification
// URI is the first param you pass to the Route facade

protected $except = [
    'create/record', 'update/record'
];
```

Your route file might look like this:

```
Route::post('create/record', ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you try all of these steps:

1. Ensure that your session is well configured, the easiest way is to make it file and make sure storage folder has chmod 755 permission then in your `.env` you set it like below, file session driver is the easiest way to set.

   ```
   SESSION_DRIVER=file
   SESSION_DOMAIN=
   SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
   ```
2. Ensure Cache folder is cleared and writable, you can do this by running below artisan command.

   ```
   php artisan cache:clear
   ```
3. Ensure folder permissions are well set, they should be configured like below:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 755 storage
   sudo chmod -R 755 vendor
   sudo chmod -R 644 bootstrap/cache
   ```
4. Ensure your form has `@csrf` token included.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried this before .It didnt work